# Make object appear right in front of camera OCULUS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, position, oculus

I am making a Unity game for Oculus VR using C#.

I want to test a simple jumpscare where the object appears suddenly right into your "face".

I have problems with setting the position of this object. Right now I pass players position and rotation to this function.

```
public void ScareMe(Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot){
    girlSmiling.transform.position = new Vector3(pos.x, 0.9f, pos.z-    1.3f);
    //girlSmiling.transform.LookAt (pos);
    girlSmiling.transform.rotation = rot;
   //other irrelevant stuff
}
```

I need to maintain y position for my scare (girl) because in Oculus your height is adjustable and it doesn't correspond to your environment, so I need to leave it at 0.9f. 
I tried LookAt function but it doesn't work as good as I would like it to work.

The problem remains that girl appears right in front of me only when I look straight. When I move my head around, which is more likely to be a real in game situation for Oculus, she appears a bit to the right or left or even at the back.

I dont understand why it is happening. How can I set her position so she is always facing me right in front of me?

Answer (score 1):

You always can try to make your scare girl being children of your camera-head object. Doing this the object will follow the camera head and rotate with it.

```
girlSmiling.transform.parent = ...Here you can put the transform of the Camera head.
```

You can position the object before parenting or after parenting them (with local position should be easier).

I hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: It doesn't work:( I set the parent to the camera transform, but the girl doesn't even show up now. I tried to set her position before setting the parent but she still didn't show up.

Comment: Ok try this:

1 - Make the object child of the camera
2 - Se the LOCAL position of the smiling girl to the forward position of the camera.

This code:

        transform.parent = Camera.main.transform; // or your camera object//
        transform.localPosition = Camera.main.transform.forward;

After this change, if you cannot see the object in your camera, please, check the NEAR value of your cameras and make them smallers.

Comment: @Romaldowoho with the negate to the z-index, I would never expect to be able to see an object attached to the head object of the child. The line pos.z-1.3f would attach the girl to the back of your head, thus when you turn around in VR you will never see her :(